# Get Subgraph for Neo4j embedded graph database using Java

Tags: java, database, graph, neo4j, subgraph

I want to get the first hop neighbour nodes of some given set of nodes. After getting all the neighbour nodes, i want to get all the relationships existing between these neighbour nodes. I am not able to write cypher query for this.

Comment: Please show us what cypher statement you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MATCH (somenode)-->(neighbor)-[r]->(neighborsNeighbor)<--(somenode)
RETURN r
```